# Get default value if there is no data for the query?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure where I query the data for some time interval. So I have written the below query to be executed in the stored procedure:

```
SET @quer = CONCAT('INSERT INTO tmp (`time_interval`, `cnt`, `dat`, `txn_id`) (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(\'', tmpStart, '\', \'%H:%i\') as time_interval , COUNT(v.id) as cnt
     , date(v.timestamp) as dat, \"', _txn_id, '\" as txn_id FROM vehicle v WHERE v.timestamp BETWEEN \'', tmpStart, '\'
                        AND \'', tmpEnd, '\' ', _where_clause, ' GROUP BY time_interval)')
```

But the problem, I want it to insert 0 for the time interval for which there is no value.

```
Actual : for 01:00 - 02:00 = 12
         for 03:00 - 04:00 = 10
Expected:for 01:00 - 02:00 = 12
         for 02:00 - 03:00 = 0
         for 03:00 - 04:00 = 10
```

Please can anybody suggest how can I change the query to get this result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use coalesce function, if column is null, then coalesce function put your value as default, example below:

```
SELECT id, ..., coalesce(columnWithNulls, DefaultValue) FROM ...
```

Comment: I edited like this: COALESCE(COUNT(v.id), 0) as cnt but it's still the same. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: That's weird. Coalesce should work, like a charm. What result is returning by your select query ? Im specially interested about cnt column. You can also try case syntax.

`select (case COUNT(v.id) is null [OR WHATEVER INVALID COUNT WILL RETURN]  THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(v.id) END) as cnt ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try Using IFNULL function

`SELECT IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(\'', tmpStart, '\', \'%H:%i\'),'0') as time_interval`

Comment: No, it's not working. I want to have cnt as 0 there is no value for it.

Comment: Instead of inserting from resultset of a select query, You can insert all the time_intervals and date at once into table tmp.

And later you can use update query with IFNULL(colwithnull,'default value').

For eg 

`insert into tmp (`time_interval`, `dat`) values ('01:00 - 02:00','2015-07-01')`

And later

`update tmp set `time_interval`=(SELECT IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(\'', tmpStart, '\', \'%H:%i\'),'0')))`

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer using this query. Union ALL with the default value 0.

```
SET @quer = CONCAT('INSERT INTO tmp (`time_interval`, `cnt`, `dat`, `txn_id`) Select * FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(\'', tmpStart, '\', \'%H:%i\') as time_interval , COUNT(v.id) as cnt
 , date(v.timestamp) as dat, \"', _txn_id, '\" as txn_id FROM vehicle v WHERE v.timestamp BETWEEN \'', tmpStart, '\'
                    AND \'', tmpEnd, '\' ', _where_clause, ' GROUP BY time_interval UNION ALL SELECT DATE_FORMAT(\'', tmpStart, '\', \'%H:%i\') as time_interval , 0 as cnt
 , date(\'', tmpStart, '\') as dat, \"', _txn_id, '\" as txn_id) AS A GROUP BY A.time_interval');
```